# Remember a half-typed command while I check something

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh

I often find myself in the following position: I've started typing a long command at the bash prompt, but half-way through I find out I need to check something with another command. This is a problem when I'm at the console (no X), which is often the case, because then I only have the following unsatisfactory ways to do it, that I know of:

- Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and log in on another virtual console, and find out what I wanted, then go back and continue

  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, type echo + <kbd>space</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, find out what I wanted, press <kbd>↑</kbd> until I find my command, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>del</kbd> x 5, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, and continue

  Highlight what I've typed so far with my mouse (if gpm is running, which it usually is), press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to interrupt, find out what I wanted while being careful not to use my mouse to highlight stuff, then press middle mouse button on a new prompt and continue

  Pray to the command line gods that the half-written command will have no adverse effects but simply fail, and gingerly press enter, then find out what I wanted, press uparrow until I get my command back, and continue

  Jump into my time machine, travel back in time and remind myself to start screen before starting to type command, travel back to the present, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>, find out what I wanted, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd>, and continue

So what I want to know is, is there some more elegant way of doing this? A sort of subshell-command or similar?

I'm most interested in methods that do not require any preparations or setup to work.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A somewhat faster version of [alex's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/remember-a-half-typed-command-while-i-check-something/10835#10835) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (which moves to the front of the line and then cuts everything forward) is to just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, which cuts backward on bash, and the entire line (regardless of your current position) on zsh. Then you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to paste it again

Comment: Testing this, I conclude that Ctrl+U does not move back and cut forward, but rather cuts backwards. Having cursor in the middle of the command leaves whatever is behind it on the command line. Still a 33% improvement over @alex's solution though, since it saves a keystroke.

Comment: @lazyr Oh, quite right; on `zsh` it does cut the entire line, but on `bash` it cuts backwards. I never noticed that difference before

Comment: Oh, I didn't know Ctrl+U also puts text to kill buffer.  Nice to know! :)

Comment: `^U` `^K` will have the same effect as `^A` `^K` but is marginally more ergonomic, and significantly more convenient under `screen`.

Answer (score 55):

Do ctrl-A to get to start of line, prepend a hash and press return - this way it will stay in the command history as a comment and you can get back to it with cursor up

EDIT: just noticed this is a slightly more elegant variant on your #2 ;)

Comment: Yes, and why didn't I think of that? Thank you!

Comment: I need to read before I post my own answer.  James has it right on.

Comment: Note that this will not work in `csh` or `zsh` because they do not allow comments in the interactive shell. In `zsh` you need to activate the proper option: `setopt interactive_comments`.

Comment: @Sam Yes, but ": command" has the same effect (":" = the null command)

Comment: @barrycarter: no, `:` should be considered harmful for this purpose and never, ever be suggested. It will execute everything after a semicolon, inside backticks etc. with all the associated side effects.

Comment: Note that this will work better than prepending `echo ` if there are multiple commands on the line (delimited by `;`, `&&`, etc.).

Comment: @barrycarter As Sam mentioned that's a really dangerous idea, but I'm not sure it was clear how many things fall into his "etc." box. Very notably shell redirects are still processed meaning this habit will clober files. Also some forms of variable assignment will still run as will subshells, process and command substitution, etc. Interactive aliases will be replaced and more. In other words 95% of what would normall happen in a shell still happens and will happen wired up no a noop command instead of the one intended, which will almost certainly screw up your workspace.

Answer (score 30):

Hit `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+K` to move to the start of line and delete (kill) to the end of it.  Then do your research, and when ready to continue hit `Ctrl+Y` (yank) to put your saved (killed) line back.

Comment: Ah, now this is more like what I had in mind. And I do that all the time in Emacs, should have thought about doing the same on the command line.

Answer (score 15):

In zsh, I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to “suspend” the command I'm typing and type another command. After I've run that command (or aborted it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), the suspended command comes back for edition (even remembering the cursor position). As an additional convenience, if the command line is empty when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the key invokes the `bg` built-in instead (so a double <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends a running command directly to the background).

```
fancy-ctrl-z () {
  emulate -LR zsh
  if [[ $#BUFFER -eq 0 ]]; then
    bg
    zle redisplay
  else
    zle push-input
  fi
}
zle -N fancy-ctrl-z
bindkey '^Z'          fancy-ctrl-z
```

I don't know how to do something similar in bash.

In any shell, you can use the low-tech method of [adding a `#` at the beginning of the current line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/remember-a-half-typed-command-while-i-check-something/10827#10827).

Comment: your function is admirable, but did you know that `zsh` has a function for that [built in already](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/remember-a-half-typed-command-while-i-check-something/11982#11982)? It's called `push-line` and all you need to do is use `bindkey` to get to it.

Comment: @Caleb: I don't know why I use `push-input` rather than `push-line` here, `push-line` does seem more appropriate (maybe old versions of zsh only had `push-input`?). But that's not a replacement for the rest of the function.

Comment: As far as I can tell the only difference is the same-binding effect to background a running job. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Caleb: No, it's just that I find the combination of the two both convenient (`push-line` is useless on an empty line, having `bg` on `Ctrl+Z` is only useful when I've just suspended that process with `Ctrl+Z`) and mnemonic (I'm either backgrounding the process or the partial command line).

Comment: @Caleb `push-input` suspends the whole input buffer, whereas `push-line` suspends only the current line. If I'm  typing a multiline command, I want to suspend the whole command, so `push-input` is the right one. I find `push-input` more often useful than `push-line` (if I want to delay a line in a multiline input buffer, I can simply navigate to the beginning of the line and insert a newline), so I in fact wonder why `push-line` got the default keybinding and not `push-input`.

Comment: @Caleb: two comments & a question: (1) very nice hack to bind this to ^Z and do a bg on an empty line! (2) it's a bit better to do a `zle get-line` before the `zle redisplay` --- this makes it work fine for cases like: `^Z` to suspend something, start a command, `^Z^Z` to bg the something and continue editing; (3) is there any need for the `emulate -LR`?

Comment: @EliBarzilay (2) That's intended behavior: backgrounding a job with ^Z^Z doesn't automatically recall a previously-suspended command line. (3) I think in this case there isn't, but I have the habit of including it in functions that might be used in interactive sessions with all kinds of “crazy” options for user preferences.

Comment: @Caleb, re (2) with that addition it only does the recall if you ^Z^Z while typing a new command, which fixes a weird thing that happens without it.  Just it with your version: `sleep 10 RET` `^Z` `pwd` (no enter) `^Z^Z` -- at this point it *will* bg-es the sleep, but it leaves you with an empty line, and after another `RET` you get the restored line.  Then try the same sequence with my addition.

Comment: @EliBarzilay Once again, that's the behavior I intended. If you prefer to recall the line automatically, then by all means include the call to `get-line` in your configuration.

Comment: Here's a [variation](https://gist.github.com/sebastiancarlos/762ac6da14a3180f7ce2409889a6de81) of the Ctrl-Z solution, which should work for Bash.

Answer (score 14):

In bash, just type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>.

Then when you're ready, press <kbd>Up</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>.

The first puts a `#` at the start of the line to turn it into a comment, then accepts the line, as if you had pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then, when you do it a second time, it sees the line already has a `#` at the start, so it removes it, and accepts it, again saving you the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

If the second time just inserts another `#`, then you have to type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> instead.

You can make zsh do the same by putting

```
bindkey -M emacs '\e#' pound-insert
```

in your ~/.zshrc.

Or, if you are using vi bindings, you can type <kbd>#</kbd> from command mode in both bash and zsh.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the second command meant to remove the # just adds more #'s to the front.

Comment: Does the first one work?  What version of bash are you using?

Comment: Alt+# works as you describe in your third paragraph, but not as in your fourth, it simply prepends another # to the front and accepts the line. I use bash 4.1.5(1)-release on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Oh dear, in bash it requires a numeric argument, e.g. `Esc+1` then `Alt`+`#` to toggle.

Comment: That works, but is a lot more cumbersome than just Ctrl+A Del Ctrl+E, especially on my keyboard layout where Alt+# is in fact Alt+Shift+3.

Comment: Definitely.  There might be a solution to bind `Alt`+`#` to `numeric-argument` `insert-comment`, so you don't also have to type `Alt`+<number or minus> first.

Comment: You can also prepend `Esc` instead of pressing `Alt`.  This might be more palatable for removing the `#`: you can do `Esc` `1` `Esc` `#`.

Answer (score 11):

One of my favorite features in `zsh` is the builtin push-line function that takes care of this without any of the hackery in other answers here. I have it bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> in my `.zshrc` file like this:

```
bindkey '^L' push-line
```

Then when I'm typing along in some command and need to do something else real quick I can invoke that with one key and get a blank prompt. After running the other command, the prompt is automatically filled out with what I was typing before.

You can even chain multiple layers of this and the commands will come back at you in reverse order that you pushed them into the queue.

Comment: Bound to `Ctrl+Q` and `ESC q` by default (in emacs mode).

Comment: Is there something similar for bash?

Comment: @Magnus: Please review the rest of the answers on this question. There are solutions for bash, just not as elegant as this.

Comment: @Caleb, I should have been more specific, is there a similar *single key combination* for bash?

Comment: This is clearly the “correct” answer, for Zsh anyway!  I just want to mention the `push-line-or-edit` widget, which is not bound in any keymap by default.  At the top-level prompt it does the same thing as `push-line`, but at any prompt level lower down it convert the entire command being entered to a multi-line buffer.  Two great functions on one keybinding!  I can recommend binding `push-line-or-edit` instead of plain `push-line`. You lose nothing, and gain useful functionality.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> trick, if you're in screen, just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> to detach then reattach with `screen -r`

You could also just open another window with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: If you're in screen, just open another window with `Ctrl+A c`.

Comment: @Gilles .. unless you need to use some aspect of the shell state (variables, functions, aliases, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way, not perfect though, press `Ctrl-X` `Ctrl-E`. This will open your default editor containing your half typed command. Then you may save your command to a file or open a new shell from within your editor. When you exit the new shell it will return you to the editor and saving the contents will automatically execute them.

This is not perfect because it doesn't return you to your original shell, but either forces the execution of the command or completely discards it. But there are no temporary selections or kill buffers to worry about, and there are also some nice tweaks, e.g. if editor=vi

```
:wq            # execute the command
:cq            # cancel and abort
:! command     # execute command
:shell         # open a new shell
:r filename    # insert the contents of a file for editing
:r ! command   # insert the output of a command for editing
```

Comment: Very nice alternative. I'm vi-emacs-agnostic, so I'll be happy as a clam using this when powertools are really needed. (Speaking of vi, I tried the N64 linux emulator Mupen64Plus a while ago. Esc quits the emulator without saving. I soon gave up playing anything.)

Comment: @lazyr, for debian/ubuntu run `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` and choose your favorite editor. For other systems set the EDITOR or VISUAL environment variables to your favorite editor, e.g. add `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano` in your .bashrc.

Answer (score 3):

Using zsh, if you type `<ESC> q` (escape, then Q), your prompt line will be cut, so that you can type another command. You will automatically get back your cut text in the next prompt.

It can remember several lines at the same time, so you can use it while a line is waiting for you. You can even use it on blank line to delay the resume of your cut line.

It's not the most efficient way if you have to use several commands for the checking/preparation (you'll have to retype `<ESC> q` before each command). But I think that it is possible to bind it to a shorter shortcut.

---

If you just want to check the manual, type `<ESC> h` (escape, then H). That will run the `run-help` built-in, with the first word of the command line as argument. You'll find back your line intact once done.

Comment: Most terminals will let you do `M-q` instead of `<ESC> q`

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the method of adding `#` at the start of the line, there is an arguably simpler method that I use that doesn't require returning to the beginning of the line:

Just **add an open quote and don't close it,** whether single or double.

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

The partial command is saved in the command history (available via up arrow) but is not actually executed.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently written a script for this. Just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to remember/restore command-lines.

**Download:**

Visit the [repository](https://github.com/your-diary/Command-Line-Stack-for-Bash).

**Demo:**

[image: demo]