# Shell: send foreground process to background without suspending it?

Tags: bash, shell, job-control

I have a command I'm running in the background,

```
fnordctl &
```

Occasionally I pull it up into the foreground,

```
fg
```

Now, I'd like to send it back to the background to continue running. Typing Ctrl-z will suspend the process, and it won't continue running until I run `bg`.

Is there a way I could background the process without suspending it?

If that's not possible, maybe there's a way I could bind the suspend operation and subsequent `bg` to a shortcut key (e.g. Meta-z)? I'm using Bash, so maybe this is something I could create a custom Readline binding for?

Comment: [How do you send command line apps directly to the background?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70724/how-do-you-send-command-line-apps-directly-to-the-background) is probably a better candidate/

Comment: Not a duplicate since this question does not ask for the first attempt.