# Suspend a process silently with ctrl-z

Tags: bash, vim, zsh

With my current workflow, I frequently use CTRL-z to suspend Vim so I can enter a quick few commands before resuming editing my code with fg (actually, it's CTRL-z again, [thanks to the handy ZSH tip on this blog post](https://sheerun.net/2014/03/21/how-to-boost-your-vim-productivity/)). The issue is, my terminal ends up being cluttered with job suspension messages which is distracting from the output I wish to see.

Unwanted output:

```
[1]  + continued  vim

zsh: suspended  vim
```

The following screenshot shows what this can end up looking like in a standard session:
[image]

So my question; **is there a way to stop CTRL-z and fg printing any output?**

Comment: I don't think so. You probably should consider using `screen` or `tmux` to avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: “I could not find a solution, so I developed one on my own” *[ahem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/remember-a-half-typed-command-while-i-check-something/10851#10851)*

Comment: Looking at the source, neither bash nor zsh seem to have a way to avoid these messages.

Comment: @Gilles That's unfortunate. Thanks anyway though, if you are sure then could you put this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: why don't you run command from inside `vim` using `:! your_command`?

Comment: @Jakuje I do when it makes sense to, however if I need to run a couple a git or system commands consecutively then it's normally a lot easier to suspend the session. I guess I can always settle for a tmux split open in the same directory.

Comment: I usually have several terminals open... it lets me look at compilation errors and at the code at the same time. Other than that, what @otheus said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to break the pipe. However, the progressing program cannot be called by `fg` anymore.

You can fist abandon the job to `init` by command `disown -h JobID|PID` after running `bg JobID|PID`. And then you can close the terminal.

The program won't stop. It will more like a daemon since then. However, it can't get anything from `stdin` and it's output to `stdout` and `stderr` will be neglect.

Comment: Although this didn't quite achieve what I wanted it does technically answer the question, so I'll mark this as correct.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if messages for interactive sessions can be easily changed. But your problem can be solved as Jakuje suggests with a subshell from Vim. Instead of running your command, just `:!zsh` or `:!bash` and when you're done `exit`.

Comment: Of course you could map this in Vim to make it even easier than C-z and use C-d to exit the shell and return to Vim.