# When is it necessary to include `emulate -LR zsh` in a function invoked by a zsh widget?

Tags: zsh

I've included in my `~/.zshrc` the following code:

```
fancy-ctrl-z () {
  if [[ $#BUFFER -eq 0 ]]; then
    bg
    zle redisplay
  else
    zle push-input
  fi
}
zle -N fancy-ctrl-z
bindkey '^Z' fancy-ctrl-z
```

... which I found in an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10851/232487) to the question [Remember a half-typed command while I check something](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10825/232487).

It works, but originally the code contained this statement:

```
emulate -LR zsh
```

I looked for the `emulate` command inside `man zshbuiltins` to understand the `-L` and `-R` options.

It seems that `emulate -R zsh` resets all the options to their default values, which I checked with this command:

```
vimdiff <(setopt) <(emulate -R zsh; setopt)
```

However, if I execute `emulate -R zsh` in an interactive shell, it resets the options definitively, so I suppose that's where the `-L` flag is needed:
to make the new values of the options local to the current function (if any).

It also seems to imply that options can have a local value, in addition to a global one, and that in case of a conflict, the local one has priority.

So, `emulate -LR zsh` is used to re-create a local environment with default and predictable values for the options, in which the author of a widget doesn't have to wonder what the options will be when its function is invoked, or to save (at the beginning of the function) then restore (at the end) all the options which may change the intended behavior of the widget.

I didn't copy the line because it seems to work without it. However, I would like to know if my understanding of this command is correct, and if someone could provide one or two simple examples, where `emulate -LR zsh` is necessary to avoid side effects.

Comment: That seems a mighty complicated way to write `bindkey "^z" push-line-or-edit`

Comment: @thrig The whole point of this function is to do something different when the command line is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

`emulate -R zsh` resets all options to the zsh defaults. The `-L` flag makes this local to the containing function (and more generally makes all option changes local to the function).

Putting `emulate -LR zsh` near the beginning of a function definition is good hygiene when the function is meant to be used in contexts where options are potentially different, especially in interactive shells.

In this particular instance, `emulate -LR zsh` is not needed, because the code is not affected by any option. But it doesn't do any harm.

Here are some examples of options that a user may set in their initialization file, or that may be disabled by surrounding code that calls the function, and that can break a function:

- Turning off [`bare_glob_qual`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-BARE_005fGLOB_005fQUAL) breaks the use of glob qualifiers.
- Turning off [`care_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CARE_005fGLOB) or [`case_match`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CASE_005fMATCH) would make some pattern matching case-insensitive, even though it might not make sense in the function.
- [`null_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NULL_005fGLOB) and [`csh_null_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CSH_005fNULL_005fGLOB) affect the behavior of glob patterns that match no file.
- [`numeric_glob_sort`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NUMERIC_005fGLOB_005fSORT) can break a function that requires patterns to be expanded in lexicographic order.
- [`err_exit`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-ERR_005fEXIT) and [`unset`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-UNSET) can cause errors where the function's code intended the default behavior (ignore a command's status, treat an undefined variable as empty).

Comment: That code may be affected by `errexit` and is affected by `posixidentifiers` (for `$#BUFFER`). Note that most widgets shipped with `zsh` use `-L` instead of `-LR`. With `-R`, you're also resetting things like `xtrace` which may not be desirable.