# Running a subshell from the middle of the current command

Tags: command-line, zsh

I frequently find my self in this scenario. I'm in the middle of typing a command and I need to check something else before I complete it.

Is there a way to open a subshell of some sort with my current input so far being remembered, then when I exit this subshell I'm back to where I was?

```
$ mylongcommand -n -e <SOME KEY COMBINATION WHICH OPENS A SUBSHELL>
$ date
...
$ exit
$ mylongcommand -n -e <BACK TO WHERE I WAS>
```

I'm using `zsh`

Comment: Why not just open another terminal window?

Comment: @Barmar For me, I don't use a GUI on most of my linux systems so I would have to switch TTY's. Which means I have to re-authenticate. The options below are much more efficient.

Comment: You could use `screen` or `tmux` to get multiple virtual terminals on the console.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is the key combination <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> which saves the command buffer and allows to enter a new command. After running the command the buffer contains what you typed before. If you have to run another command before finishing this you can type <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> again.

(I didn't try to open a subshell after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> yet.)

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_10.html and search for "esc-q"

Comment: This exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot! I could make it run a nested shell instead of returning straight away but for my use case returning straight away works perfectly.

Answer (score 18):

I typically use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> which erases the current line and saves it into a buffer. From there I do what ever it was I needed to before the `mylongcommand`. Then when I am ready I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to paste `mylongcommand` back in my prompt.

[Remember a half-typed command while I check something](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/remember-a-half-typed-command-while-i-check-something)

Answer (score 7):

My solution to this is decidedly low-tech and clunky, but relies on key-sequences you're probably already familiar with: Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>#</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

This has the effect of inserting a `#` at the start of the line, thus making it a comment, then executing it, thereby pushing it into the command history.  You may then enter your auxiliary command, then scroll up through the command history to the commented command, remove the `#` and complete the command as needed.

Comment: You should press the "home" button on your keyboard, it saves 1 keypress, and the energy required to actually press it

Comment: @Ferrybig - yes, that's good, though for my my day-to-day keyboard is a MacBook Pro which doesn't have a **HOME** key.  The **HOME** equivalent is **FN** + **LEFT ARROW**, but that scrolls up to the top of the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to “suspend” the command I'm typing and type another command. After I've run that command (or aborted it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), the suspended command comes back for edition (even remembering the cursor position). As an additional convenience, if the command line is empty when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the key invokes the `bg` built-in instead (so a double <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends a running command directly to the background).

```
fancy-ctrl-z () {
  emulate -LR zsh
  if [[ $#BUFFER -eq 0 ]]; then
    bg
    zle redisplay
  else
    zle push-input
  fi
}
zle -N fancy-ctrl-z
bindkey '^Z'          fancy-ctrl-z
```

(Previously posted at [Remember a half-typed command while I check something](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/remember-a-half-typed-command-while-i-check-something) which mainly has solutions for bash, where you can't do anything so convenient. This is a slightly fancier version of [the built-in binding of `M-q` to `push-line`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506075).)

This doesn't run a subshell: the command that you type after “suspending” the previous one runs in the same shell. This lets you do things like changing the current directory if you realize after typing a command that you meant to run it in a different directory. If you want to run a new shell instance, you can run `zsh` from a key binding, but I don't think that's particularly useful.