# Make auto completion options remain on screen in zsh, like bash

Tags: bash, zsh, autocomplete

As Apple rolled out the first developer previews of macOS Catalina, it seems like they have made the default shell into `zsh`, instead of the good old `bash`. I've kept myself at Mojave, but nonetheless I've decided to switch to `zsh` first and get familiar with it.

While all the new features are cool and all, I don't quite like how `zsh` folds/hides away all the auto completion items after I press control-c or return. In `bash`, the items remain on the screen, and it's really convenient to refer to in subsequent commands. For example, when I do `cd`, I quickly press tab twice to give it a `ls` effect on the fly. Now with `zsh`, it no longer works.

It's not really a deal-breaker, but I certainly want that behavior back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to customize completion, starting with [some boolean options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Completion-2). I think the effect you're after is to turn off [`always_last_prompt`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#nidex-ALWAYSLASTPROMPT).

```
setopt no_always_last_prompt
```

Funny, I've seen the opposite question a lot: people who are used to zsh tend to hate the bash behavior where completing something causes previous terminal commands to scroll away. If you want an `ls` effect in zsh, you can [suspend the current command and run `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/remember-a-half-typed-command-while-i-check-something).