# Key binding to swap shell foreground/background jobs

Tags: shell, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, job-control, jobs

In spite of heavy `tmux` use and switching between panes, I still frequently find myself using shell job control. When something needs poking I'll background the tool I'm using with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, poke the thing, then `fg` the tool again. The issue is sometimes the "poking" turns into using another tool and I want to go back and forth a couple times.

Would it be possible to bind another key that is trapped by the shell (i.e. not ever passed though to a foreground app) that backgrounds the current job and foregrounds whatever the most recent background job is?

Comment: You can't have a key that goes directly to the shell because it isn't reading from the terminal. You can have a tmux binding that sends a succession of keys but it might be tricky because tmux can't control who is reading from the terminal. A few keys are interpreted by the terminal and transmitted to the shell as a signal, e.g. Ctrl-z → SIGSTOP, but you can't define new signals. Are two keys acceptable? For example I've [set up my shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a10851) so that `C-z C-z` backgrounds the foreground program, with a stop that's as brief as my ability to press two keys.

Comment: @Gilles, I'd be happy with `C-z C-z` backgrounding one job and forgrounding the other, yes. I do wonder if any of the existing signals could be clobbered instead. There are a couple I don't care about, and even have disabled (`C-s` for example).

Comment: `C-s` is a terminal action that doesn't send a signal. The only signals are `C-c` → SIGINT, `C-z` → SIGTSTP and `C-\` → SIGQUIT. If you're happy with `C-z C-z`, I suggest that you adapt my function to select whichever foreground job you want.

Comment: Giles you linked to a 404.

Comment: I think the link should be https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10851

Answer (score 1):

This makes issuing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> immediately resume the previous job, as long as you have more than 1 job suspended. The only way to exit the while loop is to close programs until at most 1 backgrounded program is left.

```bash
function fgstack() {
  local n_jobs=$(jobs | tr -cd "[:digit:][:space:]" | wc -l)
  while [[ n_jobs -gt 1 ]]; do
    fg %-;
    n_jobs=$(jobs | tr -cd "[:digit:][:space:]" | wc -l)
  done
}
```

If you want to give yourself a chance to break out from the two-job loop, suspending a job before before 0.2 seconds has passed does it <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>: (zsh -- for bash you would need to use something else for getting the time):

```
function fgstack() {
  local n_jobs=$(jobs | tr -cd "[:digit:][:space:]" | wc -l)
  while [[ n_jobs -gt 1 ]]; do
    if [[ $SECONDS -lt 0.2 ]]; then
      break
    fi
    typeset -F SECONDS=0
    fg %-;
    n_jobs=$(jobs | tr -cd "[:digit:][:space:]" | wc -l)
  done
}
```

Here's another, that requires [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) but gives you a menu if you have more than two options to choose from:

```
function fgstack() {
  local n_jobs=$(jobs | tr -cd "[:digit:][:space:]" | wc -l)
  while [[ n_jobs -gt 1 ]]; do
    if [[ n_jobs -eq 2 ]]; then
      fg %-;
    else
     job=$(jobs | fzf -0 -1 | tr -cd "[:digit:]") && fg %$job
    fi
    n_jobs=$(jobs | tr -cd "[:digit:][:space:]" | wc -l)
  done
```

Tested in zsh and bash -- bash seems to exit the while loop after returning from the first backgrounded job after invoking the function, edits & comments are welcome if someone knows how to fix that!